# NgRx Testing - Subscribe callback not updating during test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, karma-jasmine, ngrx

I'm trying to test a component which edits shopping list items.
When first loaded, the pertinent state values it receives via subscribing to `store.select` are:

```
editedIngredient: null,
editedIngredientIndex: -1
```

With these values, it'll ensure that the class' `editMode` property is set to `false`.
During testing, I am trying to update the state once the component has loaded.
What i'm trying to achieve is updating the `editedIngredient` and `editedIngredientIndex` properties to a truthy value in my component, hence allowing the `editMode` prop to be set to `true`.

When trying the below code, I am able to get the component to render and `editMode` is initally set to false.
Once the state is updated inside my test however, the `store.select` subscriber does not update, meaning the test just finishes without `editMode` ever being set to true.

Component code (ShoppingEditComponent)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._subscription = this.store.select('shoppingList').subscribe(stateData => {
    if (stateData.editedIngredientIndex > -1) {
      this.editMode = true; // I want to update my state later so that I set this value
      return;
    }
    this.editMode = false; // I start with this value
  });
}
```

Test code

```
let store: MockStore<State>;
const initialState: State = {
  editedIngredient: null,
  editedIngredientIndex: -1
};
const updatedShoppingListState: State = {
  editedIngredient: seedData[0],
  editedIngredientIndex: 0
};

let storeMock;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule],
      declarations: [
        ShoppingEditComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({ initialState }),
      ]
    });
});
```

Test Attempt 1

```
it('should have \'editMode = true\' when it receives a selected ingredient in updated state',
  fakeAsync(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShoppingEditComponent);
    const componentInstance = fixture.componentInstance;

    // no change detection occurs, hence the subscribe callback does not get called with state update
    store.setState(updatedShoppingListState); 
    expect(componentInstance['editMode']).toEqual(true);
  })
);
```

Test Attempt 2

```
it('should have \'editMode = true\' when it receives a selected ingredient in updated state',
  fakeAsync((done) => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShoppingEditComponent);
    const componentInstance = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      store.setState(updatedShoppingListState);
      expect(componentInstance['editMode']).toEqual(true);
      done();
    });
  })
);
```

- The problem I am having with attempt 1 is that the change detection doesn't occur.
- The problem I am having with attempt 2 is that the change detection doesn't occur if I omit the `done()` callback.
  However, if I include the `done()` callback, I get an error stating that `done() is not a function`

For reference:
I found the example for mocking the store from [the NgRx docs](https://v8.ngrx.io/guide/store/testing) (i'm on Angular 8, so this example is most relevant for me)

I am using Karma/Jasmine for my tests.

Any guidance would be really helpful.

Comment: I also tried adding "{ provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true }" to my provider, but then the initial state received in the subscribe callback was undefined, so the component logic crashed, hence failing the test.

Comment: Did you try using `fixture.detectChanges()` after `store.setState(updatedShoppingListState); ` ? (referring to 1st attempt)

Comment: Yes, I tried this before posting, but it made no difference.

Comment: haven’t used “provideMockStore” yet, but shouldn’t it be: “provideMockStore({ shoppingList: initialState })” ?

Comment: Unfortunately no - provideMockStore just takes a property named ```initialState```. It's not possible to provide a custom property name like ```shoppingList```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I think I've found the problem.

Let's have a look at [`provideMockStore`'s implementation](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/testing/src/testing.ts#L20-L33):

```js
export function provideMockStore<T = any>(
  config: MockStoreConfig<T> = {}
): Provider[] {
  return [
    ActionsSubject,
    MockState,
    MockStore,
    { provide: INITIAL_STATE, useValue: config.initialState || {} },
    { provide: MOCK_SELECTORS, useValue: config.selectors },
    { provide: StateObservable, useClass: MockState },
    { provide: ReducerManager, useClass: MockReducerManager },
    { provide: Store, useExisting: MockStore },
  ];
}
```

The `config` object that can be given to `provideMockStore` has this shape:

```js
export interface MockStoreConfig<T> {
  initialState?: T;
  selectors?: MockSelector[];
}
```

As you can see, the value at `config.initialState` is *assigned to* the `INITIAL_STATE` token, which is further injected in `Store`(`MockStore` in this case).

Notice how you're providing it:

```js
const initialState: State = {
  editedIngredient: null,
  editedIngredientIndex: -1
};

provideStore({ initialState })
```

This means that `INITIAL_STATE` will be this:

```js
{
  editedIngredient: null,
  editedIngredientIndex: -1
};
```

This is how [`MockStore`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/4f7dcdc6b4b3721fd565103014bf4ba2ed69b3a0/modules/store/testing/src/mock_store.ts#L40) looks like:

```js
 constructor(
    private state$: MockState<T>,
    actionsObserver: ActionsSubject,
    reducerManager: ReducerManager,
    @Inject(INITIAL_STATE) private initialState: T,
    @Inject(MOCK_SELECTORS) mockSelectors: MockSelector[] = []
  ) {
    super(state$, actionsObserver, reducerManager);
    this.resetSelectors();
    this.setState(this.initialState);
    this.scannedActions$ = actionsObserver.asObservable();
    for (const mockSelector of mockSelectors) {
      this.overrideSelector(mockSelector.selector, mockSelector.value);
    }
  }
```

Notice it injects `INITIAL_STATE`. `MockState` is simply a `BehaviorSubject`.
By calling `super(state$, actionsObserver, reducerManager);` you're making sure that when you do `this.store.pipe()` in your component, you'll receive the value of the `MockState`.

This is how you're selecting from the store:

```js
this.store.select('shoppingList').pipe(...)
```

but your initial state looks like this:

```js
{
  editedIngredient: null,
  editedIngredientIndex: -1
};
```

With this in mind, I think you could solve the problem if you do:

```js
const initialState = {
  editedIngredient: null,
  editedIngredientIndex: -1
};

provideMockStore({ initialState: { shoppingList: initialState } })
```

Also, if you'd like to dive deeper into `ngrx/store`, you could check out [this article](https://indepth.dev/understanding-the-magic-behind-ngrx-store/).

Comment: This set me on the right path in order to get my test functioning - thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the `store.select` subscriber to update, thanks to Andrei's input.
The following is what I needed to do:

```
import * as fromApp from '../../store/app.reducer';

const seedData = getShoppingListSeedData();
const mockInitialAppState: fromApp.AppState = {
  shoppingList: {
    ingredients: seedData,
    editedIngredient: null,
    editedIngredientIndex: -1
  },
  ... default state of other store types' defined in AppState are also provided
};

describe('When an item is selected', () => {
/* In the question code, I was passing the ShoppingList 'State' type into MockStore<T>,  
   whereas it should have been the AppState, as we see on the next line 
*/
    let store: MockStore<fromApp.AppState>;

    const shoppingListState: ShoppingListState = {
      ingredients: seedData,
      editedIngredient: seedData[0],
      editedIngredientIndex: 0
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [FormsModule],
        declarations: [ShoppingEditComponent],
        providers: [
          // this ensures that "shoppingList: initialState" is part of the initial state, as per Andrei's suggestion
          provideMockStore({ initialState: { ...mockInitialAppState } })
        ]
      });
      store = TestBed.get<Store<fromApp.AppState>>(Store);
    });

    it('should have \'editMode = true\' and form values should be set to name and amount of the selected ingredient',
      fakeAsync(() => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShoppingEditComponent);
        const componentInstance = fixture.componentInstance;

        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges();

        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {

          store.setState({
            ...mockInitialAppState,
            shoppingList: {
              // the updated state
              ...shoppingListState,
            }
          });

        });

        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(componentInstance['editMode']).toEqual(true);
      })
    );
  });
```

To summarise, the mistakes I was making were:

- Incorrectly passing in the initial state to the store
  Instead of passing in the store type of `shoppingList` to `provideMockStore`, i was passing in a store type of `ingredients`, `editedIngredient` and `editedIngredientIndex`
- Defining the store type incorrectly
  Instead of defining my mock store with type `AppState`, I was only defining it as being of type `ShoppingListState`.
  This meant there was a type mismatch between the store in my test and the store in my component.

This resulted in store updates received by the component during the test being `undefined`.